# How can i use nested serializer inside the same serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class UserViewSerializer(DynamicFieldsMixin,serializers.ModelSerializer):
    followers_set = UserViewSerializer(required=False,many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields  = ('id','email','username','password','followers_set')
        depth = 2
```

is there anyway i can use this function without getting this error?

```
    followers_set = UserViewSerializer(source='follows',required=False,many=True)
NameError: name 'UserViewSerializer' is not defined
```

i tried SerializerMethodField but then i can't use depth option there

```
following_set = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_following_set(self, user):
        return UserViewSerializer(User.objects.filter(follows__author=user), many=True).data
```

using SerializerMethodField gives me error of:

```
RecursionError at /api/users/
maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Create additional serializer for Followers instead, you probably don't want followers of followers anyway

Comment: I have to.I am creating a social media system. That's why i want to use depth to limit the usage of it.

Comment: @umarbeyoglu: if you make two extra serializers, one without `followers_set`, and one *with* `depth = 1`, then you simply have a "three stage" serializer.

Comment: You can still have proper API endpoints which would check if that is follower of follower instead of dumping big JSON that would result in loading hiccups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to handle this is to make three serializers: one without a `followers_set`, one with a `followers_set` that uses the previous one, and one that users the second model, so:

```
# no followers_set
class UserViewSerializer0(DynamicFieldsMixin,serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields  = ('id','email','username')

# followers_set, but only depth 1
class UserViewSerializer1(DynamicFieldsMixin,serializers.ModelSerializer):
    followers_set = UserViewSerializer0(source='follows',required=False,many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields  = ('id','email','username')

# followers_set, with depth 2
class UserViewSerializer(DynamicFieldsMixin,serializers.ModelSerializer):
    followers_set = UserViewSerializer1(source='follows',required=False,many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields  = ('id','email','username')
```

This is more safe as well, since you can not define recursive loops, unless you indeed work with `SerializerMethodField`, which is not a good idea if you add extra serializers.

It might however be better no to go to depth two, but stick to depth one. It will generate large responses already, make creating objects more cumbersome, and it will result in a lot of extra queries.